Velocity of conduction electron in a metal in an alternating electric field
This is a exercise from a book.

Suppose the conduction electrons in a metal are subjected to an
alternating electric field \$E = E_0 \cos(ωt)\$ applied along the x-direction.  Let \$V_x\$ represent the average x-component of the velocity of the electrons and let \$τ\$ be their relaxation time. Set up the equation of motion for an electron and show that
$$v_x(t)=-\frac{eE_0}{m}\left[\frac{\cos ωt}{1+ω^{2}τ^{2}}+
 \frac{ωτ \sin ωt}{1+ω^{2}τ^{2}}\right]$$
where m is the electron mass. Note that the first term in the brackets
is in phase with the field, whereas the second lags 90 degrees behind the field. From this result, show that the frequency dependence of the  conductivity is given by  $$σ(v) = \frac{σ_\text{static}}{1+ω^{2}τ^{2}} $$

Attempted solution:
$$  {\frac{\partial v_x} {\partial t}}_\text{collision} +  {\frac{\partial v_x} {\partial t}}_\text{other} = \frac {d}{dt}(v_x)= 0 \tag{1}$$
Now,
\$ {\frac{\partial v_x} {\partial t}}_\text{other} \$ is due to the electric field i.e. acceleration of electron due to electric field. Hence,
$$ {\frac{\partial v_x} {\partial t}}_\text{other} =  {\frac{\partial v_x} {\partial t}}_\text{field} = -\frac{eE}{m} \tag{2} $$
The average velocity of an electron after interacting with the lattice of metal would go to zero in time exponentially as
\$ \langle v_x \rangle_t = \langle v_x \rangle_0 e^{-\frac{t}{τ}} \$
τ is called relaxation time.
\${\frac{\partial v_x} {\partial t}}_\text{collision} =  - \frac{1}{τ}\langle v_x\rangle \$
From (1)
$$ -\frac{eE}{m} - \frac{1}{τ} \langle v_x\rangle = 0 $$
or
$$ \langle v_x \rangle = -\frac{eτ}{m}E  $$
Average velocity
$$ \langle v_x \rangle = -\frac{eτ}{m}E_0 \cos ωt $$
This is not the same as in the question. Can you write what other steps are required to get the answer as in the question?
Reference: Electrical Engineering Materials - A.J. Dekker, PHI, 2014, pages  126-129, 149, 150

Which book? And I'm curious about the units of $E_0$. I'm probably misinterpreting $e$. What is it, exactly?

Oh, in case it helps, note that $\frac{\cos\omega t}{1+\omega^2\tau^2}+\omega\tau\frac{\sin\omega t}{1+\omega^2\tau^2}=\frac{\cos\left(\omega t-\tan^{-1}\omega\tau\right)}{\sqrt{1+\omega^2\tau^2}}$.

periblepsis, $E_0$ is magnitude of Electric field at t=0. Its units are Volts/m.The book is Electrical engineering materials by A.J Dekker. Thanks for the breakdown of cosine expansion.

I expected $E_{_0}$ should be volts/meter. But I'm having a problem with the dimensions, I guess. They don't produce the expected results (for me.) Thanks for mentioning the book.

$B $ is the symbol for magnetic field strength. Its units are $weber / m^2$.

Yes, I know that, too. Teslas. I'm looking at the first equation in the exercise itself. There's no $B$ there. What's in the brackets is unitless. On the left, I take it is $\frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}$. On the right, before the brackets? The $E_{0}$ is as you say. Does $\frac{e}{m_e}\times E{_0}$ yield $\frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}$?

$\frac {eE_0}{m}$ is acceleration and has units of $meters/s^2 $. F = QE is the equation for force where E is electric field and Q is charge. so $\frac{QE} {m}$ becomes acceleration.

I was thrown off by the naming of $v$.

I used < > for naming as $<v_x> $ because it was notation of the book.
